# Magento 2 create product duplicate Image are Doubled Issues

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, duplicate

when saving product with the duplicate in Magento 2 then
images are double like,

Pics get doubled when duplicating an item, so the duplicated item has two images. If you duplicate that then the new item has four images. We just need one image when duplicating an item.

If any suggestion then let me know,

please ASAP,

Thanks,